# ASP.net Page_Load does not seems to be called

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am new to asp.net. My **login.aspx** page has this line:

`<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Users.aspx.cs" %>`

and my **Users.aspx.cs** file has following lines of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;


public partial class Users : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            LoginButton.Text = "My form is valid!";
        }
    }   

}
```

On the **login.aspx** page I am using

> *RequiredFieldValidator* and
>   *RegularExpressionValidator*

to validate Email and Password fields.

Now, I have to make sure that the validation is complete and do further stuffs. But, my code is not being friendly here; it's not caling any of those two functions. As a matter of fact, I feel like it's not even getting into the **.cs** page. I know I am making some silly mistake here.
Thank you!

**P.S. Validation is working fine, it's returning error messages correctly.**

**Edit: Login.aspx** page looks like below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Users.aspx.cs" %>

                <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3 toHide" id="loginBlock">
                    <div class="card-header"><b>Login To Pay Your Bills Online</b></div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="emailToLogin">Email address<b class="text-danger">*</b></label>
                                <asp:TextBox id="emailToLogin" ValidationGroup="Login" runat="server" placeholder="Enter email" CssClass="form-control"  />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="emailToLogin1" EnableClientScript="false" ValidationGroup="Login" CssClass="small text-danger" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" controltovalidate="emailToLogin" errormessage="Please enter your email!" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="passwordToLogin">Password<b class="text-danger">*</b></label>
                                <asp:TextBox id="passwordToLogin" ValidationGroup="Login" TextMode="password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" CssClass="form-control"  />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="passwordToLogin1" EnableClientScript="false" ValidationGroup="Login" CssClass="small text-danger" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" controltovalidate="passwordToLogin" errormessage="Please enter your password!" />


                            </div>
                            <div>

                            </div>
                            <asp:Button id="LoginButton" ValidationGroup="Login" runat="server" OnClientClick="LoginButton_Click" Text="User Login" CssClass="btn btn-warning"  />  

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: why do you have your `Page_Load` declared as `function` make it private void or protected void. also there are plenty of free online tutorials on asp.net basics I would suggest reading them and viewing the working examples and understand the `Page Life-Cycle`

Comment: I am just adding Page_Load just for test purpose. That will be removed later.

Comment: go to msdn and google how to declare the Page_Load method signature ... this is not Java or javascript. `Also read up about PostBacks` and what object / controls inside a web page, trigger postbacks

Comment: I have read there and other tutorials. I even tried out solutions for similar issues. Nothing worked out so I bothered to post here. By the way, thanks for the down vote.

Comment: did you read any tutorials on the basics or did you just jump in and start trying what you saw in the tutorial without reading / understanding..?

Comment: Make sure your LoginButton control on your login.aspx page has the OnClick defined, for example: OnClick="LoginButton_Click"

Comment: @Laslos; yes it has <asp:Button id="LoginButton" ValidationGroup="Login" runat="server" OnClientClick="LoginButton_Click" Text="User Login" CssClass="btn btn-warning"  />

Comment: Can you post your .aspx page?

Comment: Yes I have updated the question by including the aspx page as well. Thank you @Laslos

Comment: Add Inherits="Users" to your .aspx file after the CodeFile attribute

Answer (score 1):

OnClick will work on server side , OnClientClick will execute on client side before control passed to server.
So, Either you need to define OnClientClick function ClientSide or change OnClientClick to OnClick.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(VS.80).aspx